# Amazon Lex and DynamodDB - can't update existing item

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-lex, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to get a specific item from a table.

My DynamoDB table name is `table` and I have:

```
Name PK | Number<br/>
S: Juan |  S: #####
```

When I try to run in Lambda I don't get any Item when it really exist one with that name... any idea why it's like that?

```js
AWS = require("aws-sdk"),
          DDB = new AWS.DynamoDB({
              region: "REGION",
          }),
          lookup_name_str = name //From Intent variable,
          params = {
              TableName: "table",
              KeyConditionExpression: "name = :v1",
              ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":v1":{
                    "S": lookup_name_str
                }
            },
              FilterExpression: 'contains(nomColaborador,:v1)',
              ProjectionExpression: "Number"
          }; 
      
      console.log(params);
      var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
      docClient.scan(params, function(err, data){
          if(err){
              throw err;
          }
          
          if(data.Items && data.Items[0] && data.Items[0].Number){
              console.log("There is a Name with that number");
              console.log(data.Items[0]);
              my_response.statusCode = 200;
              my_response.body = {
                  "sessionAttributes": {
                      "extension_str": data.Items[0].Number.S,
                      "nomColaborador": event.currentIntent.slots.Name
                  },
                  "dialogAction":{
                      "type": "Close",
                      "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
                      "message": {
                          "contentType": "PlainText",
                          "content": data.Items[0].Number.S
                      }
                  }
              };
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that you are doing a `scan`. `KeyConditionExpression` isn't a parameter of a scan request. If you are requesting a single item by key you want to use `getItem`. If you need to query data by partition key and an optional sort key you should use `query`.

With that all said, when you do a scan, or put a filter on a query, you really need to be sure to page through the data. You will often find that you'll get a response with no data, but a paging key to make another call.